# "the website encountered an unexpected error.Please try again later" after db_update

Tags: 7, database, forms

Drupal responses "the website encountered an unexpected error.Please try again later" after running db_update statement in my custom module. I always do this without any error. Any suggestion pls!

```
function mobile_user_form_submit($form, $form_state){
    $deposit=$form_state['values']['deposit'];
    $status =$form_state['values']['status'];

    $id = $form_state['values']['hid'];
    drupal_set_message(t($id ." / ". $deposit." / ".$status));
    if($id != ""){
    db_update('mobile_users') 
        ->fields(array('deposit' => $deposit, 'status' => $status, "updated" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')))
        ->condition('id', $id)
        ->execute();
    drupal_set_message(t('successfully saved.'));   
   }
}
```

After comment db_update() statement, it is ok no error message show.

Thank you,

------ Solved -------

And I try to update manually that record in mysql, in the field "deposit" I got an error message "Please select a value not more than 127". I found myself I set wrong datatype in deposit field, I was willing to set Integer datatype but I was not awared what I had set I set tinyint. After chaning tinyint to integer, "the website encountered an unexpected error.Please try again later" also removed.

Thanks

Comment: Check your watchdog and apache logs for a more useful error message.

Comment: @rooby, thanks so I have install watchdog module, you said apache logs, I am not familiar with apache logs how can I find apache logs in window with xampp.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719549/where-does-phps-error-log-reside-in-xampp - I would think that maybe there might also be a menu item in the tray icon for viewing PHP error but I could be wrong as I don't use it.

Comment: since you solved the problem, please be sure to add that as an answer and accept it, so the question does not remain unanswered in the system

Answer (score 1):

Once try to insert manually in mobile_users(phpmyadmin) table with same data.
Then check for any errors, if not then check recent logs/apache error logs for more suggestions.